# Local content URL from UIWebView

Tags: ios

I'm writing an ios app that uses a `UIWebView` to display local html content as a help subsystem. The user can follow links to other local html content and I want to be able to tell what page the `UIWebView` is currently displaying.

I have tried `webView.request.URL.absoluteString` and similar variants but it gives me the app bundle and not the local html file within. How can I get the name of the local file being accessed?

Answer (score 1):

try this

assuming your html file resides in your bundle.

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your_File_Name" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

hope to be helpful to you.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am loading the pages with no problem. When a user follows links I want to keep track of what page they are  currently viewing.

Comment: Ok , try reading this link, may be helpful to you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679378/iphone-uiwebview-get-the-url-of-the-link-clicked

Comment: In that link they are using `webView.request.URL.absoluteString` which as I've said I've tried. I assume they are using web addresses and the problem occurs with locally loaded html files.