# How to get the url that UIWebView is loading?

Tags: iphone

In my WebView, when the user clicks on a link within the webview, where is that property?  I looked at the docs and have tried things like

```
[webView.request.URL description]
webView.request.URL.absoluteURL or absoluteString
```

, and everything is blank.  Thanks!

Comment: Use the search feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679378/iphone-uiwebview-get-the-url-of-the-link-clicked

Answer (score 3):

Implement delegate function like

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        // Its following the click on some link on the loaded webpage
        NSString  *strLink = [[request URL] absoluteString]; // Clicked Link URL
    }
    return YES; // return YES if you allow the page to load else return NO  
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
NSString *link = [webView.request.URL absoluteString];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch webview delegate functions when user tap on any link

> ```
> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
>   NSURL *url = [request URL];
>   NSString *link =   [url absoluteString];
>   return YES;   
> }
> ```