# Objective-C - Open webview within webview

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, facebook

I am new to Objective-C, as I'm from android background. I implemented a functionality in android, which is now needed to be implemented in IOS.

I have a webview which opens up a webpage. User clicks the facebook login button on there which fires up popup as a new webchromeclient within the webview. Once login, I replace the webview with original one and capture the cookies. Page automatically determines user's login status and opens up user's profile page.

Here is my layout for activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0099cc"
        tools:context=".MyActivity"
        android:id="@+id/webview_frame">
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String target_url="https://www.mywebpage.com/login";
    private static final String target_url_prefix="www.mywebpage.com";
    private static final String target_url_profile= "http://www.mywebpage.com/profile" ;

    private WebView mWebview; //To Hold original page
    private WebView mWebviewPop; //To hold facebook login popup
    private FrameLayout mContainer; //Framecontainer to replace webviews

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

        mWebview  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);

        //To check login status and other stuffs
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
        mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);
    }

    //
    private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();

            //If host is actually my webpage, remove popup and dont override
            if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) 
            {
                if(mWebviewPop!=null)
                {
                    mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                    mWebviewPop=null;
                }
                return false;
            }

            //If this is a facebook login popup, dont override
            if(host.equals("m.facebook.com"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url); //Just reading cookies here
            if(cookies != null && !cookies.isEmpty()) {
                //Further logics with cookies
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            if(cookies != null && !cookies.isEmpty()) {
                if (isUserloggedinFacebook(cookies)) { //Check user login status from cookies
                    if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                        mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                        mWebviewPop = null;
                    }
                    mWebview.loadUrl(target_url_profile); //User is loggedin, load profile page
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
            mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
        }
    }

}
```

This code is needs to be written in Objective-C but I am not sure how to override url and replace webview. I tried creating two separate webviews, but after login with facebook, I can't return back to original webview and read cookies.

Can someone help?

Comment: what is it that I am receiving so many downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
      NSURL *url = [request URL];
      yourTextBox.text =   [url absoluteString];


      return YES;   
}
```

the above is the code equivalent to android's `shouldOverrideURL` you can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679378/iphone-uiwebview-get-the-url-of-the-link-clicked) for more info.