# Get url when a link is clicked in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to get the url of the link when it is clicked in UIWebView .

I am using this code

```
  NSString *currentURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", webview.request.URL.absoluteString];

        NSLog(@"Current URL == %@",currentURL);
```

It gives me null

```
Current URL == (null)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone - UIWebview - Get the URL of the link clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679378/iphone-uiwebview-get-the-url-of-the-link-clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
In Webview Method :

```
     - (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType{
             NSURL *url = request.URL;
             NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);
            NSURL *url = request.URL;
            NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);
            if ([url.host containsString:@"www.google.co.in"])
            {
               nslog(@"Google")
            }else{
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you set webview  delegate in storyboard?

Comment: How to do some action when i get desired URL.

Comment: Above Method is call every time when webview's URL Change.I edit my answer for that

Comment: @Ammy can you get your answer?