# Pass url from UIWebView 1 in ViewController 1 to UIWebView 2 in ViewController 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have UIWebView in my first ViewController, and I want if the user clicks on any link inside UIWebView 1 should open new ViewController (ex. InfoViewController) and passes the URL to new UIWebView inside InfoViewController.

EDIT:

[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy8Kn.png)

My Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL (string: "https://google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webview.delegate = self;
    webview.loadRequest(requestObj);

}

func webview(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked) {
    //Push to new view controller here and pass new url:
    let url = request.URL
    let infoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InfoViewController") as! InfoViewController
    infoViewController.passURL = url.absoluteString //Add passURL property in your InfoViewController

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(infoViewController, animated: true)

    //prevent the current webview from loading the page
    return false
    }

    //webview will load first time normally/other requests will load
    return true
}
```

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the webview delegate to self:

```
webview.delegate = self
```

And then you can add this delegate method. This runs whenever it tries to load a url. You can add a if check to make sure it is a link they have clicked and run your code to change screen and prevent the current webview from loading the url by returning false:

```
//Update: got method name wrong:
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
         //Push to new view controller here and pass new url:
         let url = request.URL
         let infoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InfoViewController") as InfoViewController
         infoViewController.passURL = url.absoluteString //Add passURL property in your InfoViewController

         self.navigationController!.pushViewController(infoViewController, animated: true)

         //prevent the current webview from loading the page
         return false
    }

    //webview will load first time normally/other requests will load
    return true
}
```

Comment: Not working, can you please chick above my code & storyboard and advice.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, got the method name wrong, should be webView not WebViewNews and wasn't calling the method. Try now

Comment: Thank you so much bro. You save my life.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pull the link from your first UIWebview:
   [iPhone - UIWebview - Get the URL of the link clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679378/iphone-uiwebview-get-the-url-of-the-link-clicked)
2. Open the new ViewController and pass the string.
3. Direct your second UIWebview to open the URL.